# Best way to create string filter comparation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal's create a filter `search` function, in particular actually I'm using `.indexOf` method that allow me to check if two string are equal. The problem's that if I've the compare string with space break like this: `Hair Cut`.

Example:
String to search: `Hair`
String contained in the object: `Hair Cut`

```
var cerca = $('#filter_service').val();
for(var i = 0; i < GlobalVariables.availableServices.length; i++) {
    if (cerca.toLowerCase().contains(GlobalVariables.availableServices[i].name.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        console.log(GlobalVariables.availableServices[i].name)
    }
}
```

How you can see I valorize the variable `cerca` that contains the string `Hair` in the example. I compare this with an object variable, how I said, the problem is if I insert the string `Hair` I get no response in console, also if I insert the string with break space like the compare string `Hair Cut` I get the console response.

How I can print a result also when the variable `cerca` is equal to the first character of the compair string? In particular `Hai`?

I don't know if I was clear, hope yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.contains()` is for checking DOM element children. You said above that you are using `.indexOf` to check, but it doesn't look like you use it in your code?

```
var cerca = $('#filter_service').val();
var searchIn;

for(var i = 0; i < GlobalVariables.availableServices.length; i++) {
    searchIn = GlobalVariables.availableServices[i].name.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (j = 0; j < searchIn.length; j++) {
        if (cerca.toLowerCase().split(' ').indexOf(searchIn[j].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            console.log(GlobalVariables.availableServices[i].name);
        }
    }
}

$('#filter_service').on('input', function() {
    var inputStr = $('#filter_service').val();
    var similar = [];
    for (i = 0; i < GlobalVariables.availableServices.length; i++) {
        if (GlobalVariables.availableServices[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputStr.toLowerCase) >= 0) {
            similar[similar.length] = GlobalVariables.availableServices[i].name;
        }
    }
    // At this point, you can do whatever you want with the similar service
    // names (all of the possible result names are included in the array, similar[].)
});
```

I can't test that code right now, but in theory, it should work.

Here is a JSFiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/MrGarretto/vrp5pghr/

EDIT: Updated and fixed my errors

EDIT 2: Added the 'possible results' solution

EDIT 3: Added a JSFiddle

Comment: yeah, sorry I've paste the solution that I'm actual trying.

Comment: also your code give this error: Uncaught TypeError: cerca.toLowerCase(...).split(...).includes is not a function

Comment: Whoops! Just updated my answer; it should work without errors now

Comment: No problem, for the break space working perfect, but it's possible create a code that if I insert the first letter print the result of the correspond object that I'm trying to find? It will be helpfull, thank you.

Comment: I just adding a possible way to do this, but I'm not sure if it's exactly what you were asking for. The solution I provided simply returns an array of `GlobalVariables.availableServices` names that contain the text in `filter_service`, and it updates each time the text in it is changed.

Comment: Okay but the last code that's start with filter_service is another code? Could you please provide a JsFiddle? Thanks

Comment: Okay - I just added one to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this solution it's very great.